# how to remove following arguments after the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

destroyer(array1, some arguments) function should return the array1 excluding the arguments. I found some working ways like `return arr = arr.filter(val => !rem.includes(val));` but  I need to fix this code and find out why this code giving an incorrect result. It supposed to be [1]

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...rem) {  
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {      
      if (rem.includes(arr[i])) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
      };    
  };
  return arr;  
}

console.log(destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the call of the function `Array.prototype.splice` within the for loop, this function is mutating the array and basically affects the indexes of the array, therefore the current index `i` is no longer valid.

To work around this, you can loop in a backward direction, this way we can mutate the array, and the current index is not affected.

One more thing, your approach is mutating the array, a better approach would be by using the function `Array.prototype.filter` along with the function `Array.prototype.includes`, see other answers.

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...rem) {
  for(let i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {      
      if (rem.includes(arr[i])) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
      };    
  };
  return arr;  
}

console.log(destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...rem) {  
const itemsToRemove = new Set(rem);
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => itemsToRemove.has(curr) ?  acc : [...acc, curr] ,[])
}

console.log(destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this:

```js
const destroyer=(arr, ...rem)=>arr.filter(v=>!rem.includes(v));

console.log(destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5));
```